# How can i get current Tab URL inside chrome-extension which is created by react

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have an iframe appended to the main website body where I have attached my index.html( React generated), Now by using useeffect hook to get the current tab URL. Unforunately i m getting `chrome-extension:/asdhiakdjhaldiuada/`

My content.js look like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage)
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
//plugin css
iframe.style.background = 'white'
iframe.style.height = '100%'
iframe.style.width = '0px'
iframe.style.position = 'fixed'
iframe.style.top = '0px'
iframe.style.right = '0px'
iframe.style.zIndex = '9000000000000000000'
iframe.style.fontFamily = 'Lato'
iframe.style.transition = '0.5s'
iframe.frameBorder = 'none'

function gotMessage(payload, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (payload.message === 'SIGNAL_TAB') {
    //react generated HTML
    iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('./index.html')
    iframe.className = 'pligin_identifier'
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    window.linkedin_url = payload.eventTab.url
    window['linkedin_url'] = payload.eventTab.url
    localStorage.setItem('linkedin_url', payload.eventTab.url)
    toggle()
  }
}

PS I have tried window object, localStorage and tried retrieving in useEffect hook, But no luck, Great if someone help
```

Comment: Inside the iframe you can use chrome.tabs.getCurrent with a callback that receives the current tab object.

Comment: Thanks, Its be resolved i was able to access chrome API in useEffect, i have silented chrome not defined error and build the app, its working